# Azure Deployment: missing web.config

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps

I am trying to deploy a vanilla node js app using the swagger yeoman generator as described in the Azure docs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-nodejs-api-app/.

When deploying however, the app is trying to look for a `web.config` file that should've been generated automatically by Azure as part of the deployment process.

What would I need to do to deploy my Azure app successfully?